# Nextcloud Docker status keeps "Restarting (255)"

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, nextcloud, docker-compose

I'm running a Nextcloud instance in docker-compose on my Raspi 4 at home for some years now and update the images about every two months.
My pi stopped working during todays NC update from 25.0.3 to 25.0.4 and i had to reboot (via pulling the plug) my it. But now my Nextcloud-container won't work anymore. Docker Status is constantly on "Restarting (255)" and even if i try to start the container attached, there is no more output on console then "nextcloud exited with code 255" and "*docker logs nextcloud*" command has no output.

```
> docker-compose up nextcloud
    mariadb is up-to-date
    Starting nextcloud ... done
    Attaching to nextcloud
    nextcloud exited with code 255
```

I tried to remove the images and even tried the old version, but it keeps exiting with code 255. Any ideas how to fix this?

This is my docker-compose file for Nextcloud:

```
services:
  nextcloud:
    container_name: nextcloud
    image: nextcloud:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=mariadb:3306
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=***
    volumes:
    - /media/myCloudDrive/nextcloud:/var/www/html
    - /media/myCloudDrive/configs/apache2.conf:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
    - /var/run/redis/redis.sock:/var/run/redis/redis.sock
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason. During the update the local php files in the folders "core" and "lib", as well as the file "version.php" got cleared. All files were 0kb in size.
I fixed this by starting a new Nextcloud instance on my PI and moved all the affected files into my main installation. Running `occ upgrade` and `occ maintenance:repair` did the rest. My Nextcloud ist back up again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to debug the error.
The docker container exit status "255" only means its main
entrpypoint/command process stopped with that status.
The 255 code simply means "there was an error", but does not tell you
much beside that.

For advice about debugging, see the article
[6 ways to debug an exploding Docker container](https://medium.com/@pimterry/5-ways-to-debug-an-exploding-docker-container-4f729e2c0aa8),
which describes the following commands:

```
docker logs <container_id>
docker stats <container_id>
docker cp <container_id>:/path/to/useful/file /local-path
docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash
docker commit <container_id> my-broken-container &&
   docker run -it my-broken-container /bin/bash
```

See also the
[HTTP Toolkit for Docker](https://httptoolkit.com/docker/),
an open-source tool to help with Docker debugging.

Comment: I managed to enter my container with a new entrypoint "/bin/bash" and the option "tty: true". But i can not execute an occ command. If i run "php occ" as www-data i get this output:
`An unhandled exception has been thrown:
Error: Class "OC" not found in /var/www/html/console.php:67
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/occ(11): require_once()
#1 {main}`